# Is there a way in Eclipse to determine what is eating CPU time?

Tags: eclipse, performance, plugins

I am using Eclipse for Java development.  I have a number of plugins (Maven, Subversive, JBoss reverse Engineering tools, etc), and the system seems to hang fairly consistently, to the point where it can be 10-20 seconds from a mouse click until it responds.  I have given it a gig of memory in the configuration, and it is not even using half of that.  When it hangs, it completely pegs one of the processors, and I see large numbers of Page File Deltas.

Is there any way to see what is happening inside Eclipse?  Which plugin could be causing the problem?

I believe (although I am not positive) I am running Eclipse 3.5.2.  I am running on Windows XP, SP 2 or 3 (I do not manage the machine, my company does, so I am not positive how up to date it is).

Comment: To give an example, I opened up the help->about dialog to check the version while writing this post.  When I hit "OK" on it, it took right around 14 seconds (rough guesstimate, I was counting without a stopwatch) for Eclipse to become "responsive" again (i.e. repaint when something stopped covering it up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the one plugin that can help investigation this would be **[MAT (Memory Analyzer)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)**.
[Full tutorial at Vogella](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html).

Second, make sure to use an **[optimized eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659)** launched with the latest JDK (6u22) and check if the issue persists then.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  I did change my .ini to be closer to the optimized ini you linked, and that helped.  I am going to install the MAT addon/plugin sometime today.  My empirical testing evidence suggests that there is a problem with Subversive, but hopefully MAT will make that more clear.